# Setting VTIMEZONE tags breaks my ICS file

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I have created an ICS file that I include in my emails through my web app, the times specified are in UTC time, this needs to be applied as in my testing it appears the Calendar client will assume the timezone is the users local time.

Here is what my ICS file looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oWo53UAC
DTSTART:20200814T194500
DTEND:20200814T204500
SUMMARY:Your Appointment - Appointment Name Here
LOCATION:123 Fake Street, New York, New York, 1234
DESCRIPTION:
ORGANIZER;CN=:MAILTO:
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a0F8E00000oWo59UAC
DTSTART:20200814T220000
DTEND:20200814T230000
SUMMARY:Your Appointment - Appointment Name Here
LOCATION:123 Fake Street, New York, New York, 1234
DESCRIPTION:
ORGANIZER;CN=:MAILTO:
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have added `VTIMEZONE` tags around my `EVENT` node. I have also specified the timezone at the top like `TZID:UTC`.

This doesn't appear to work. Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: You may find if helpful to read the specification on VTIMEZONE definitions (which define a timezone and do NOT wrap VEVENTS). https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-5-time-zone-component.html.   Read also the spec on adding timezones to VEVENTS.  See Form #3 for DATETIME https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.5.     Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  as this info should have come up with a modicum of search on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VEVENT component must not be inside of the VTIMEZONE component!

Specify a timestamp's timezone like so:

`DTSTART;TZID=UTC:20200814T194500`